# what is the relation between these two variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following symmetrical functions
$$f_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 \tau_{ij}\ \frac{1}{c_j}$$
$$c_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 \tau_{ij}\ \frac{1}{f_j}$$
$$\tau_{ij} = \tau_{ji}$$

where $\tau_{ij}$ is given number,  $f_i$ and $c_i$ are unknown number.

I write them as matrix form
$$ \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   f_{1}\\
   f_{2}\\
   f_{3}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right] = \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   \tau_{11} \ \  \tau_{12}  \ \  \tau_{13}\\
   \tau_{21} \ \  \tau_{22}  \ \  \tau_{23}\\
   \tau_{31} \ \  \tau_{32}  \ \  \tau_{33}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   1/c_{1}\\
   1/c_{2}\\
   1/c_{3}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$$

$$ \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   c_{1}\\
   c_{2}\\
   c_{3}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right] = \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   \tau_{11} \ \  \tau_{12}  \ \  \tau_{13}\\
   \tau_{21} \ \  \tau_{22}  \ \  \tau_{23}\\
   \tau_{31} \ \  \tau_{32}  \ \  \tau_{33}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   1/f_{1}\\
   1/f_{2}\\
   1/f_{3}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$$

Can I get any relation between $f_i$ and $c_i$,say $f_i = \rho c_i$?

or can I solve for $f_i$ and $c_i$?

Comment: But what is the subindex d?

Comment: @vvnitram sorry. A typo. It's $c_j$ and $f_j$

Comment: You have 15 variables (9 $\tau$'s, 3 $c$'s and 3 $f$'s; and 9 equations (3 for $f$'s, 3 for $c$'s and $3$ nontrivial ones for $\tau$'s here).

Comment: @JustinBenfield Can I get the relationship between $f_i$ and $c_i$?

Comment: @XJ.C: Gaussian elimination (or any other method of solving a linear system, such as Cramer's rule) should suffice, note that you will not be able to get the $\tau$'s to disappear in general because the existence of the desired relationships depends on them in an essential way. Also, if the $\tau$ matrix is not invertible, then you will not, in general, be able to construct the desired relationship.